# Permutation of N numbers based on a property

Tags: algorithm

I have a Number N and String S. I have to create an array of size N containing permutation of numbers from 0 to N-1 indexing from 0 to N-1 such that for 0 to N-2, if:

```
S[i]=='1'   then A[i]>A[i+1]
else A[i]<A[i+1]
```

I have to find the number of ways to create this array.

**Problem:** I know this can be solved using dynamic programming but the main problem is, how do I keep track of the numbers that that have been used.

If N is between 1 to 25 then `I can use dp[1<<n][n]`. Where `Mask` tells me the number being used, how can this be solved when is N is up to 3000.

How can I keep track of the numbers that are used in a sequence since each number can be used only one time?

```
For Ex:
3
S =11
Ans = 1
The only permutation that satisfies the given pattern is (2,1,0).
```

Comment: Do not forget to mention that you try to cheat in an ongoing programming competition and that in 4 games the answers would be visible in that contest

Comment: Cheater in a programming competition: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w18/challenges/gg